# Can't get AndroidViewClient example code to run

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) is a github repo that allows you to call on views directly, without specifying exact coordinates with monkeyrunner. I'm having trouble actually using it though.

*Note: I'm using Windows*

In cmdline if I type:

```
monkeyrunner test.py
```

and test.py consists of:

```
# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

# Presses the Menu button
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

Then the actionBar overflow button get's clicked.

If I edit test.py to any of the AndroidViewClient examples it will doesn't do anything.

Any ideas? I'm not sure if I'm implementing AndroidViewClient correctly.

**EDIT:**

The only thing I did to setup AndroidViewClient is download the .zip from github and then I added it to my environment variables like this:

[image]

When I try to run `monkeyrunner dump.py`:

```
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Scri
pt terminated due to an exception
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Trace
back (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EgamerHDK\android-sdk\tools\dump.py", line 29, in <module>
    from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
ImportError: No module named dtmilano

130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:264)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.imp.import_logic(imp.java:692)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:746)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:791)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1236)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:367)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1207)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:869)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:845)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(C:\Users\EgamerHDK\android-sdk\tools\dump.py:78)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(C:\Users\EgamerHDK\android-sdk\tools\dump.
py)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:538)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:77)

130419 02:46:57.869:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:18
9)
```

**Typing in the full path:**

```
C:\Users\EGamerHDK\android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner C:\AndroidViewClient-master\Andro
idViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py
Can't open specified script file
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

    -s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
    -p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
    -v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO,
WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem a problem related with AndroidViewClient but with Windows monkeyrunner in general if it cannot execute a script which is specified by its absolute path.

Comment: If I put test.py into AndroidViewClient/src it works!

Comment: Okay, I moved dump.py instead of copying by accident. Anyway... calling it works. But I still get the no module named drmilano error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dump.py changed:

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
```

to:

```
sys.path.append('C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src')
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
```

and it worked now. Here's a sample output from my app.

```
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1
   android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/2
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3
         android.view.View id/no_id/4
            android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/5
               android.widget.ImageView id/no_id/6
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/7
               android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/8
                  android.widget.TextView id/no_id/9 Tabs+SwipeCompatable
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/10
               android.widget.ImageButton id/no_id/11
         android.widget.HorizontalScrollView id/no_id/12
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/13
               android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/14
                  android.widget.TextView id/no_id/15 SECTION 1
               android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/16
                  android.widget.TextView id/no_id/17 SECTION 2
               android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/18
                  android.widget.TextView id/no_id/19 SECTION 3
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/20
         android.support.v4.view.ViewPager id/no_id/21
            android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/22
               android.widget.TextView id/no_id/23 1
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution. What you changed is exactly (well in other OSs like Linux or OSX, it is) what dump.py does: `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))`, so if you feel like exploring try to print `sys.path` content to verify what is the difference. The `\` (backslashes) perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

From [AndroidViewClient wiki](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki):

> Installation AndroidViewClient does not require installation to be
>   used. You only need to download the source distribution and set the
>   environment variable ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME or PYTHONPATH to allow
>   the monkeyrunner interpreter to find the required modules.

Expand the downloaded ZIP file and set the environment variable accordingly.

Then if you are intending to run, for example `dump.py` the next step is:

```
monkeyrunner dump.py
```

Comment: Does this environment variable look set up properly? `C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src`

Comment: This first part (`C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient`) depends on how you unzipped the file. Let's assume is correct (you can verify it cd'ing into it). The second part (`\src`) it's not needed, you have to remove it.

Comment: Okay, I believe the path is correct. Please see my updated question. I try to run dump.py but it does not work.

Comment: Can you cd into `C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient` ?

Comment: Correct! this is the directory you have to set as the value of the environment variable `ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME`.

Comment: I see. It seems that in Windows `monkeyrunner` changes the directory to `tools`. Specify the absolute path for the script: `monkeyrunner \path\to\my\script.py`

Comment: Oh I was running `monkeyrunner dump.py`, but you need me to run `monkey runner C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\examples\dump.py`?

Comment: In you command line, instead of `monkeyrunner dump.py` use `monkeyrunner \path\to\my\dump.py`

Comment: Okay, I typed out the full path. Get a different message this time. Check my updated question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28492/discussion-between-eghdk-and-dtmilano)