# Error: No module named dtmilano

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I followed the steps mentioned in the below post:
[Can't get AndroidViewClient example code to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098500/cant-get-androidviewclient-example-code-to-run)

But im still getting error "No module named dtmilano"

In my test.py file i have added the following lines :

```
sys.path.append('C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient\src')
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
```

the same is done in dump.py file

I have also set the environment variable for  AndroidViewClient.
Is there anything i missed ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is related with how the '\' (backslash) are treated, they may be *escaping* the following character.

Using **AndroidViewClient** plugin as explained [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#plugin) should solve this Windows problem.

For example:

```
c:>\path\to\monkeyrunner -plugin \path\to\androidviewclient-<version>.jar myscript.py
```